# Postgres get all fields that are not certain values (including nulls)

Tags: postgresql

I'm looking to filter a table but, the number of queries i'm expecting differ from the result.

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE name NOT IN ('matrix', 'filters')
```

That `name` column contains strings values and `nulls`. It seems like the nulls are being filtered out but, I would like them included in the result

Comment: I don't know the exact syntax, but would "where name is null or name not in ('matrix', 'filters')" do the trick?

Comment: Yep just wondering why the nulls get excluded. Makes the query confusing to read.

Comment: I found an article about null being a special value in postgress with special rules around it. "The NULL value can cause problems when selecting data, because when comparing an unknown value to any other value, the result is always unknown and not included in the final results". [https://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_null_values.htm]

Comment: Then include nulls: `WHERE name NOT IN ('matrix', 'filters') or name is null`